# JSF2 Locale handler

Tags: localization, jsf-2

I am upgrading my app to JSF 2 from JSF 1.2.

I have ran into the following issue. I had locale handler which handled the locale used by examing the URL of the request.

```
@Configurable
public class MutationViewHandler extends FaceletViewHandler {

@Autowired
private LanguageMutationServiceIface mutationService;

public MutationViewHandler(ViewHandler parent) {
    super(parent);
}

@Override
public Locale calculateLocale(FacesContext context) {
    String mutation = FacesUtil.getRequestParameter("mutation");
    if (mutation == null) {
        return new Locale(mutationService.getDefaultLanguageMutation().getName());
    } else {
        return new Locale(mutation);
    }
}
}
```

But in JSF 2 is this class deprecated and causes error (NPE) when used in MyFaces. I have tried to implement it using simple ViewHandler, but it forces me to implement many methods where I wish to use the default behaviour.

Thanks for help in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to extend [`ViewHandlerWrapper`](http://download.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/faces/application/ViewHandlerWrapper.html) instead.

> Provides a simple implementation of `ViewHandler` that can be subclassed by developers wishing to provide specialized behavior to an existing `ViewHandler` instance. The default implementation of all methods is to call through to the wrapped `ViewHandler`.
>
> Usage: extend this class and override [`getWrapped()`](http://download.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/faces/application/ViewHandlerWrapper.html#getWrapped%28%29) to return the instance we are wrapping.

So, you can just do

```
public class MyViewHandler extends ViewHandlerWrapper {

    private ViewHandler wrapped;

    public MyViewHandler(ViewHandler wrapped) {
        this.wrapped = wrapped;
    }
    
    @Override
    public ViewHandler getWrapped() {
        return wrapped;
    }

    @Override
    public Locale calculateLocale(FacesContext context) {
        // Do your thing here.
    }

}
```

Comment: Which viewHandler should I return from the getWrapped method? Is there any way to get the default one?

Comment: Just the one which has been passed-in during construction. I updated the answer with a kickoff snippet.

Comment: perfect, works for me. Its more simple than I thought, I was looking for a pitfall, but there was none :-). Thanks very much.